# The right way to use Ajax to Update a Single field in a specific Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

**Is it possible to use Ajax to Update a Single field in a Specific Object?** 
I have an postgres table with lots of records, I want to use a jquery Ajax request to update a single field in a specific object within that table. Can that be done without replacing or reposting the entire record?.

I want this (Gives me a 400 bad request error):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/MyEndPoint/',
    data: {
        id: Specific_Record,
        Field_To_Update: New_Value, 
    }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log( 'success, server says '+data);  
    }
});
```

Instead of this (which works):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/MyEndPoint/',
    data: {
        id: Specific_Record,
        Field_To_Update: New_Value, 
        Field1: SameAsBefore, 
        Field2: SameAsBefore,  
        Field3: SameAsBefore,  
        ...  
        Field16: SameAsBefore, 
    }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log( 'success, server says '+data);  
    }
});
```

*Note: I'm using Django, and could easily do this update in views.py but I want to use Javascript to avoid a page refresh.

Since I'm also using Django Rest Framework, would it be better for me to create a new endpoint that is specific to the field I want to update? ex: `/api/DB_Table/Object_id/Field_to_Update`

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can do this - it needs to be handled in your server

Comment: Set up a PUT method on your route for doing updates

Comment: Of Course! That's so obvious, I should have known that. I'll have Ajax ping the endpoint and in my views.py file (Where that endpoint logic is handled) I'll have python update  the single field in the specific object.  Thanks for your help during my Brain Fart  :)

Comment: @charlietfl it's actually PATCH not PUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can in simplest form use the `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` generic view provided by Django RestFramework library

This will expose following apis :

`GET` : `Return` object

`PATCH` : `Update` the object data (`partially`, as per convention)

`PUT` : `Update` the object data

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview

If you also want to `support deleting` object, then you can use `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`, this will support `DELETE` to delete object

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using the PATCH HTTP method and it is called a *partial update* in REST terminology. It is already implemented by default in DRF so you don't have to override any method for that. This is opposed to PUT which is a full update and will require that you add all required fields to the request unless yuou override the default behavior